# Asp.net Membership password

Tags: asp.net, web-config, asp.net-membership

I am using sql server and custom database to store membership provider tables. In my webconfig file I decreased the password strength but members still needs to apply default password strength. The following is the webconfig settings

```
 <membership>
  <providers>
    <add name = "AspNetSqlProvider"
     type = "System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, 
     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
     connectionStringName = "LocalSqlServer"
     enablePasswordRetrieval = "false"
     enablePasswordReset = "true"
     requiresQuestionAndAnswer = "true"
     applicationName = "/"
     requiresUniqueEmail = "false"
     passwordFormat = "Hashed"
     maxInvalidPasswordAttempts = "5"
     minRequiredPasswordLength = "6"
     minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters = "0"
     passwordAttemptWindow = "10"
     passwordStrengthRegularExpression = "" />
  </providers>
 </membership>
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Password needs to be 8 characters with atleast one capital letter and one alphanumeric character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set your membership provider as the default provider. Otherwise it will use the membership provider defined in `Machine.Config`.

```
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="30">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name = "AspNetSqlProvider"
 type = "System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, 
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
 connectionStringName = "LocalSqlServer"
 enablePasswordRetrieval = "false"
 enablePasswordReset = "true"
 requiresQuestionAndAnswer = "true"
 applicationName = "/"
 requiresUniqueEmail = "false"
 passwordFormat = "Hashed"
 maxInvalidPasswordAttempts = "5"
 minRequiredPasswordLength = "6"
 minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters = "0"
 passwordAttemptWindow = "10"
 passwordStrengthRegularExpression = "" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```